# How to get values in YAD when combining form and button // Exit codes for user-specified buttons

Tags: bash, yad

```
#!/bin/bash

array=$(yad \
--separator="\n" \
--form \
--field="Number":NUM 1 \
--field="Text":TEXT \
--button="b1:1" \
--button="b2:2" \
--button="b3:3" )
echo $?
echo "${array[@]}"
```

When pressing *b1* or *b3*, the *array* is empty. Why? How to modify this to get always the answer of *NUM*- and *TEXT*-form-field in the array and the button number as *$?* ?

Comment: I don't know anything about `yad`, but that `array` variable is *not* an array, it's just a plain text variable. To make an array from the command's output, you'd need some sort of parsing step to split it into separate elements. Also, `$?` is normally a success/failure status code (0 for success, nonzero for some sort of failure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manpage:

> Exit codes for user-specified buttons must be specified in command line.
> **Even** exit code mean to print result, **odd** just return exit code.

So, you need to use **even** exit codes for your buttons

---

**edit:**

I was looking for a way to *robustly* load `yad`'s output into a bash array, but the `--separator` option doesn't seem to support the `null byte`. There is however a `--quoted-output` for shells that you can use with `eval`:

```bash
quoted_input=$(
    yad --quoted-output \
        --separator=' ' \
        --form \
        --field='Number':NUM 666 \
        --field='Text':TEXT 'default text' \
        --button='b1':10 \
        --button='b2':20 \
        --button='b3':30
    echo $?
)
eval "array=( $quoted_input )"

# show the array (which stores the results)
declare -p array
```

No character in the `[0x01-0x7f]` range can break it, so it is safe.

Comment: The first button gives me an exit code of `0`, any other button gives me nothing.

Comment: @KenSharp The last backslash was a bug, I removed it.